# Web Server Interrupt Driven File Transfer

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, download

I have a webpage that currently takes an upload from a user and stores this into a directory (/upload). [Linux based Server]

I am looking for a way instead of storing this on the server/in that directory to instead transfer the file onto a local machine. [Running Ubuntu 12.04]

Assuming I already have public/private keys setup how might I go about doing this?

Current Ideas:

1. ftp transfer
2. rsync

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1) Stop running anything on the server, and forward every byte to your local box. Just run `ssh -N -R :8080:localhost:3000 remote.host.com`  This will allow anyone to hit `http://remote.host.com:8080` and get your port 3000. (If you do port 80, you'll need to SSH in as root.) Performance will be kinda bad, and it won't be that reliable. But might be fine for real-time transfer where you're both online at once.

2) use inotifywait to watch the upload dir on the server, and trigger `rsync` from the server to your local box. (Requires exposing SSH port of your box to the world.) If you sometimes delete files, use `unison` [bidirectional file sync](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) instead. (Although unison doesn't work on long filenames or with lots of files.)

3) Leave the system as-is, and just run rsync from cron on your local box. (Ok, not realtime.)

Of course, most people just use dropbox or similar.Alghough